# Wordpress change all 404 to 410 error code

Tags: wordpress, server, http-status-code-404

My wordpress site has nearly 3000 posts that was deleted recently. Instead of showing error code 404, How do I show error code 410 to all deleted or not found posts and pages?

Comment: may be this can help you. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-410/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-410/) which will come handy for you, or you can follow the given steps to achieve this without using any plugin.

1. Create a Page form WordPress Admin panel as *Error 410* (or with any name of your choice)
2. Write your content in that page which you want to show to the user.
3. After publishing the page you can get the page ID from the URL
4. Add the given code in your active theme `404.php` file.

Code for `404.php`

```
$custom_410_page_ID = 25;//Error 410 page ID
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 410 Gone");
header("Refresh: 0; url=" . get_permalink($custom_410_page_ID));
exit();
```

Now when any on visit your old URL or mistype any URL it will be redirected to *Error 410* page with 410 status code to .

Reference: [Move All 404 To 410](http://www.webhat.in/move-all-404-to-410/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! My first thought was, Can I just replace the code in 404.php with a 410 error code? I leave the file name 404.php and replace its content with 410 error code, will that work?

1. Should I put the code you have given in some sort of php code in file 404.php
2. url of my 410.php file is domain.com/410.php , how do I know its permalink?
3. what would be the content or code in 410.php ?

Comment: @BigRedDog:This is not a browser dependent and I don't think there would be any caching issue either. but just give it a trie in chrome incognito mode. and if possible can you share the URL?

Answer (score 5):

you don't need to create a page.
just add this code before the get_header(); in you 404.php template

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 410 Gone");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this one is much more easier + should be the right solution :)

Comment: Great solution. Note that the 410 will be applied on GET requests but not for HEAD. It seems that WP doesn't go through the theme on HEADs.

Answer (score 1):

On the chrome browser the above code was not working like in other browsers.I modified the above code to the code below. Now the 404 errors directs to the 410 page. I guess this is how it supposed to work. Do notify me if there are an mistake in the code i edited?

```
$custom_410_page_ID = 2242;//Error 410 page ID
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 410 Gone");
header("Location: " . get_permalink($custom_410_page_ID));
exit();
```